# Why is argc not a constant?

Tags: c++, constants, program-entry-point, argc, effective-c++

```
int main( const int argc , const char[] const argv)
```

As [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321334876) Item#3 states "Use const whenever possible", I start thinking "why not make these 'constant' parameters `const`"?.

Is there any scenario in which the value of `argc` is modified in a program?

Comment: You are free to declare `argc` as `const`.

Comment: I have seen many production quality code that do this: `--argc`

Comment: I'm thinking it has to do with C legacy, but wouldn't know how.

Comment: See an example: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/awk/awk-1.2/main.c

Comment: @LuisMachuca obviously C is born before C++

Comment: I suspect that "Use const whenever possible" refers to things passed by reference, where any modification within the function persists once the function has exited. This is not true with things passed by value, like an integer, so there's nothing to be gained by making it `const`; indeed, passing `argc` as a `const int` means that you can't then use `argc` as, say, a counter inside the function.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff : I don't agree that there is nothing to gain by making `const` a pass-by-value parameter.  See eg http://stackoverflow.com/a/8714278/277304 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/117557/277304

Comment: The historical explanation is that `main`'s function signature is unchanged since the days of Unix 7, and there *was* no `const` back then (it was a shiny new feature of C89).

Answer (score 118, accepted):

In this case, history is a factor.  C defined these inputs as "not constant", and compatibility with (a good portion of) existing C code was an early goal of C++.

Some UNIX APIs, such as `getopt`, actually do manipulate `argv[]`, so it can't be made `const` for that reason also.

<sup>(Aside: Interestingly, although `getopt`'s prototype suggests it won't modify `argv[]` but may modify the strings pointed to, the Linux man page indicates that `getopt` permutes its arguments, and [it appears they know they're being naughty](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html#CONFORMING_TO).  The man page at the Open Group does not mention this permutation.)</sup>

Putting `const` on `argc` and `argv` wouldn't buy much, and it would invalidate some old-school programming practices, such as:

```
// print out all the arguments:
while (--argc)
    std::cout << *++argv << std::endl;
```

I've written such programs in C, and I know I'm not alone.  I copied the example from *somewhere*.

Comment: -1 Re "Some UNIX APIs, such as getopt, actually do manipulate argv[], so it can't be made const for that reason also.". One can freely add a top-level `const` to `argv`, without affecting what any C function can do. Also, `getopt` is declared as `int getopt(int argc, char * const argv[],  const char *optstring);`. And here the `const` is not top level, but declares the pointers to be `const`, a promise to not modify them (although the strings that they point to might conceivably be modified).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : `getopt` _permutes_ the `argv[]` array by default, but does not modify the strings.  (The word _permute_ comes directly from the man page.)  That means that the `argv` array itself is not `const` even if the strings it points to are.  How is permuting the `argv[]` array _not_ manipulating it?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : I don't understand the -1.  The statement you highlighted was not inaccurate.  `getopt` modifies the `argv[]` array passed to `main`.  Sure, you can add _some_ amount of `const`-ness to `argv[]` and not run afoul of `getopt`, but the array itself is not `const` and cannot be `const`.  Storage passed to `main` and then to `getopt` gets mutated by `getopt`, which is all I said.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : BTW, you misunderstand the `getopt` prototype:  `getopt` can write whatever it likes to the `argv` array.  It promises not to modify the characters pointed to by the pointers stored in the `argv` array.  ie. `getopt` _can_ do `argv[0] = "42";` but it can't do `argv[0][0] = '4';`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : It's interesting... I looked up the prototype in the header, and it has `char* const* ___argv` there, but the interface actually adheres to `const char **`.  Such confusion.  I had confused the precedence of the `[]` and the `*` with respect to the `const`.  My apologies.

Comment: @Joe Z, since you're already incrementing argv, why not: while (++argv) cout << *argv << std::endl;

Comment: @Alex:  I suppose you could; it was just an example, and not intended to be exhaustive.

Comment: FYI: The GNU `getopt()` knows it does not follow the standard because it pays attention to the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable to make it behave correctly.  In particular, POSIX does not permute the arguments, and does not look for options after the first non-option argument.

Answer (score 38):

The C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) says:

> #### 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> ¶1 The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;<sup>10)</sup> or in some other implementation-defined manner.
>
> ¶2 If they are declared, the parameters to the `main` function shall obey the following
>   constraints:
>
> - The value of `argc` shall be nonnegative.
> - `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through
>     `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given
>     implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. The
>     intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup
>     from elsewhere in the hosted environment. If the host environment is not capable of
>     supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation
>     shall ensure that the strings are received in lowercase.
> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]`
>     represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the
>     program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is
>     greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]`
>     represent the program parameters.
> - The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall
>     be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
>     startup and program termination.
>
> <sup>10)</sup> Thus, `int` can be replaced by a typedef name defined as `int`, or the type of `argv` can be written as
>   `char **argv`, and so on.

Note the last bullet point.  It says that both `argc` and `argv` should be modifiable.  They don't have to be modified, but they may be modified.

Comment: Interesting.  On a semi-related note, I ran into a crash-causing bug that turned out to be because Qt's `QApplication(argc,argv)` constructor [was defined with `argc` by reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qapplication.html#QApplication).  That surprised me.

Answer (score 24):

`argc` is not normally a constant because the function signature for `main()` pre-dates `const`.

Since argc is a stack variable, changing it won't affect anything other than your own command line processing.

You are, of course, free to declare it `const` if you want.

Answer (score 8):

A top level `const` on a formal argument is not part of the function type. You can add it or remove it as you like: it only affects what you can do with the argument in the function implementation.

So for `argc` you can add freely add a `const`.

But for `argv` you can not make the character data `const` without thereby changing the function signature. Which means that it's then not one of the standard `main` function signatures, and will not have to be recognized as a `main` function. So, not a good idea.

---

A good reason for not using the standard `main` arguments in non-toy programs is that in Windows they are not able to represent actual program arguments such as filenames with international characters. That's because in Windows they are by very strong convention encoded as Windows ANSI. In Windows you can implement some more portable argument access facility in terms of the `GetCommandLine` API function.

---

Summing up, nothing prevents you from adding `const` to `argc`, but the most useful `const`-ness on `argv` would give you a non-standard `main` function, most probably not recognized as such. Happily (in an ironic way) there are good reason to **not use** the standard `main` arguments for portable serious code. Quite simply, for the in-practice they only support old ASCII, with only English alphabet letters.

Comment: If you're developing for Windows with cygwin or another libc that properly supports UTF-8 (as far as I know, cygwin is the only one at present but I have someone working on another option), the standard `main` signature works fine and you can receive arbitrary Unicode arguments.

Comment: @R they also work fine on most *nix platforms. the issue is not whether there are platforms where they work. but, **very nice initiative**, and as it happens i'm doing the same, more or less seriously

Comment: As of Windows Version 1903 (May 2019 Update), you can set an applications manifest to use the UTF-8 ActiveCodePage property so that it behaves the same as *nix based platforms in regard to 8 bit text. If you do this you don't need to use any of the Windows specific 16 bit 'W' functions to handle unicode.

Answer (score 4):

The signature of `main` is somewhat of a historical artifact from `C`. Historically `C` did not have `const`.

However, you can declare your parameter `const` since the effects of const are compile time only.

Comment: When you say "historical C" how historical are we talking here?

Comment: `const` was added to C89/C90; prior to that, it was not part of C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : You know, I had forgotten that.  I learned C in 1992.  Prior to that I was a Pascal, BASIC and assembly hacker.

Answer (score 2):

Because `argc` is a local variable (and, in C++, not a reference or something), and because the special place of `main` means that backwards compatibility shenanigans grant it a huge amount of leeway with no compelling reason to *force* applications to make it const.

```
main() {}

int main() {}

main() { return 0; }

main(int argc, char* argv[]) { return 0; }

int main(const int argc, const char** argv) { /* no return*/ }
```

these and many other variations will compile on a wide range of C and C++ compilers.

So ultimately it's not that argc isn't const, just that it doesn't have to be, but it can be if you want it to be.

http://ideone.com/FKldHF, C example:

```
main(const int argc, const char* argv[]) { return 0; }
```

http://ideone.com/m1qc9c, C++ example

```
main(const int argc) {}
```

Comment: Note that the variants without an explicit return type are no longer valid in C99, let alone C11, though compilers continue to allow them for reasons of backwards compatibility. C++ compilers should not accept the variants without a return type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yep, yet the last ideone example there (http://ideone.com/m1qc9c) is G++ 4.8.2 with `-std=c++11`. Clang also accepts it but does give `warning: only one parameter on 'main' declaration [-Wmain]`, and MSVC only protests about the missing return type specifier and lack of a reference to argc. Again, 'shenanigans' and 'leeway' :)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the historical reasons, a good reason to keep argc and argv non-`const` is that the compiler implementation doesn't know what you're going to do with the arguments to main, it just knows that it must give you those arguments.

When you are defining your own functions and associated prototypes, you know which parameters you can make `const` and which ones your function will modify.

Taken to an extreme, you could declare that all parameters to all functions should be declared `const`, and then if you had a reason to change them (e.g. decrement an index to search through an array), you'd have to make local non-`const` variables and copy the `const` arguments' values into those variables.  That makes for busy-work and extra LOC with no real benefit.  A decent static analyzer will pick up if you're not modifying the value of an argument, and recommend that you make the parameter `const`.